# How do this correctly in javascript and get all variables before print out to html?

Tags: javascript, scope

i write some function, and i called `abApi.general.getUserById` function, but when i print output to `$("#friend-requests-block")` my `name` variable is empty. i know this is javascript and i try with  `$("#friend-requests-block")` in `getUserById` callback, but then i haven't `type`. How can i fix this?

```
                for (var index in requests) {

                        var name = "";
                        var type = "";

                        if(requests[index].FriendRequestTypeId == 1) {
                            type = "private";
                        }
                        else {
                            type = "business";  
                        }

                        abApi.general.getUserById(abEnvironment.sessionToken, requests[index].FromUserId, function(response2){
                            name = response2.Name;  
                        });

                        $("#friend-requests-blocks").html($("#friend-requests-blocks").html() + "<div class=\"log-block\" id=\"friend-requests-log-"+requests[index].Id+"\"><a href=\"#\"><h2>"+ name + "("+ type +")</h2></a> <div class=\"friend-requests-buttons\" style=\"margin-top: 15px;\"> <a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" data-role=\"button\" style=\"margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;\" onClick=\"abAction.approveFriendRequest("+requests[index].Id+", 1,"+requests[index].FromUserId+");\">Accept</a><a href=\"javascript:void(0)\"data-role=\"button\" style=\"margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;\" onClick=\"abAction.approveFriendRequest("+requests[index].Id+", 0,"+requests[index].FromUserId+");\">Reject</a> <a class=\"button3\" href=\"javascript:void(0)\"data-role=\"button\" style=\"margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;\" onClick=\"abAction.approveFriendRequest("+requests[index].Id+", 2,"+requests[index].FromUserId+");\">Later</a></div></div>");    

                }
```

Comment: `getUserById` probably uses AJAX. `name` is set, but after your other code has finished running. Move your `$('#friend-request-blocks')` chunk into the same callback function as `name` is in and it should work.

Comment: In order to help you'll have to give more background information. What is abApi? Have you tried to inspect the response2 variable, does it contain any data? You can try to log it or create a breakpoint at that line.

Comment: i'm not using ajax. abApi is my "class" where i have some functions. response2.Name give me name because i log it and it's not empty.

Comment: @Blender: the `type` var will be reassigned, too, and he uses it to set the html in `$('#friend-request-blocks')`. That's another issue that the OP needs to take into account

Comment: @TomaszSzulc: You say you're not using ajax, but where does the `response2` come from? what does `getUserById` do? I'd say it either executes a query or requests data from the server-side in some way. In either case: the function that takes `response2` as an argument is async

Comment: ok, sorry my bad. ajax works in background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not **just** a scope issue you're dealing with, but the fact that `getUserById` is async, too (even more than the scope). the variable `name` won't be set until your script receives a response. Having said that, since you're using a loop, moving the `$('#friend-request-blocks').html()` bit to the success callback won't cut it: the variables `name` and `type` will be reassigned on every loop iteration. To get around this, you'll have to use a closure:

```
abApi.general.getUserById(abEnvironment.sessionToken,requests[index].FromUserId,
(function(type)
{//pass the current type as an argument to closure
    return function(response2)
    {
        var name = response2.Name;//declare local variable name, or use response2.Name
        $('#friend-request-blocks').html('html goes here with correct type: '+type+' and name: '+name);
    };
}(type)));
```

Also, I get the impression you're looping through an array, not an object, though I could be wrong. If `requests` is an array, it's best *not* to use a `for...in` loop, but a regular `for(var i;i<requests.length;i++)` loop. Google will give you a huge list of reasons as to why `for...in` on arrays isn't the best of ideas.

Comment: ok thank you i'll check it later. i haven't time so i did it on "rigid".

Comment: it's working perfectly, but i don't know what is `(type)` after function. Could you explain this?

Comment: `type` is a variable that you reassign in the loop. Because you set the html in an async function, `type` might (probably will) have changed between the time the request was sent and the callback being executed. The solution is an IIFE: a function has its own scope, so you wrap your callback in a function that takes `type` as an argument, and call it immediately, passing the current _value_ of `type` to it, hence `(function(type){`<-- type is argument name`}(type))`<-- current value of type passed as argument. this function returns another function that accesses to the arguments of its parent

Comment: In this case, when the returned function references the variable `type` it references the argument that was passed to its parent IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression), not the variable that keeps changing in the loop. The result is that each callback function has its own `type` value, that value is equal to the value `type` had when it was passed to that particular callback function. Perhaps [this](http://tech.myemma.com/iifes-javascript-control-variable-scope/) is a better explanation

Comment: @TomaszSzulc: forget the previous link, it's tedious: [here's a nice explanation](http://lostechies.com/derekgreer/2012/02/17/javascript-closures-explained/) complete with diagrams that clarify a lot. [this link](http://www.codethinked.com/preparing-yourself-for-modern-javascript-development), [perhaps this](http://reallifejs.com/the-meat/getting-closure/) could prove worth something. At first glance [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-closures-demystified/) and [this pretty dry](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/) contain some useful info